# How to add buttons to DevExpress RibbonControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, ribbon-control

I am using DevExpress WPF MVVM Framework. I want to add buttons above the "Home" tab as shown by this image. How is it possible? [image]

```
<dxb:BarManager> 
    <dxb:BarManager.Items>
        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem1" Content="About" Glyph="pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Images.v13.1;component/Images/Support/Info_16x16.png" LargeGlyph="pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Images.v13.1;component/Images/Support/Info_32x32.png" Command="{Binding ShowAboutCommand}"/>
        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem2" Content="New" />
        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="SaveCommandBarButtonItem" Content="Save" />
    </dxb:BarManager.Items>
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dua, Please visit this link http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q510019, same question has posted there. May be it will help you.

Devexpress FAQ provides facility to ask Questions, Devexpress support team can better answer to solve queries related to their tools. 
Thanks,
Tameen

Answer (score 0):

What you're willing to do is not add a **button**, but a **page**.

Take a look in this link below:

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#wpf/CustomDocument7954

---

**EDIT due to comment**

That "area" you want to add buttons is called **Page Header** in a Ribbon.

This link below shows how to but them there:

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#wpf/CustomDocument8186

I'm not sure about what sizing / positioning capabilities you will have though (considering the exact layout you intended in your image).

Comment: no, i don't want to add page, i just want to add button there

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a buttons in any place of RibbonControl because the RibbonControl is not intended to be used in this way. You should use [ribbon item links](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument7983) (buttons, sub-menus, in-place editors, galleries, etc.) combined into [groups](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument7956) and [pages](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument7955). Please review the [RibbonControl Concepts](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument7954) article for more information.
Related example: [How to create a Ribbon Control](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument8178)

If you want to add items on the right edge of the RibbonControl (Page Header Region) you can use approach described in [How to add commands to the Page Header Region](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#wpf/CustomDocument8186) article.

If you want to add items to the top edge of RibbonControl (Quick Access Toolbar) you can use approach described in [How to add items to the Quick Access Toolbar](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#wpf/CustomDocument8186) article.

P.S. I see you are using the MVVM Framework. Thus you should also review the following article: [MVVM Framework Getting Started (Lesson 2) - Customize a Ribbon and Create an About Button](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument15283)